# ASP:Net LinkButton control Postback issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-controls

I have an asp.net linkButton (or imageButton) control in my **profile.aspx** page. I'am checking Request.Querystring("id") in the page below in the code behind.

> http: //localhost:42932/profile.aspx?id=1

When I first load the profile page it is not posted back. It is ok!. When I go to another users profile (the same page just the query string is different) **using imageButton control** with the adddress;

> http: //localhost:42932/profile.aspx?id=2

it is posted back. I dont want it to be posted back. But if I go to this page with a regular html input element like

> a href = "http: //localhost:42932/profile.aspx?id=2"

it is not posted back. So I want the image button behave like an html input element.

Here is my imageButton;

ASPX:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgProfile" ImageUrl="images/site/profile1.png" runat="server"/>
```

.CS

```
imgProfile.PostBackUrl = "profile.aspx?id=" + Session["userID"];
```

Edit:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["order"] = 0;
    }
```

This control is in the page load. So it should be !postback with state I mentioned above. Because all the other functions are working when Session["order"] = 0

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `OnCLientClick` instead of `OnClick`, so that you only run client side code. Then, sepcify that you `return false;`

i.e.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgProfile" ImageUrl="images/site/profile1.png" runat="server" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

But, why use a server control, when this can be done with a normal `<img ..` html control?

Comment: that is not what I'm asking. I also want the server side code executes. But not postback!

Comment: the postback will cause the PageLoad() to execute, so put all the code you don't want running in there with a !IsPostBack, or flag it specifically with something that can skip the code you don't want run.

Comment: I edited my post please check it. Yes all my functions are working if it is not pageload.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specifying a `PostBackUrl` I would recommend using `Response.Redirect()` in the button click event handler:

```
public void imgProfile_Click(object sender, eventArgs e){
   Response.Redirect("profile.aspx?id=" + Session["userID"]);
}
```

Or alternatively, just use a `Hyperlink` control and set the `NavigateUrl` property during `Page_Load`:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="imgProfile" runat="server"><img src="images/site/profile1.png" /></asp:Hyperlink>

imgProfile.NavigateUrl = "profile.aspx?id=" + Session["userID"];
```

Comment: Response.Redirect also causes the post back in the same page. And I should use imageButton in the project :)